# Run a cursor with a substitute variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run a cursor with a substitute variable. I try to enter `Pa` and it throws the following error:

> identifier PA must be declared

```
DECLARE

CURSOR c_emp(p_cad varchar2) IS SELECT * FROM employee
                                WHERE fname LIKE ''||p_cad||'%';  
                                
v_fname employee.fname%TYPE:=&Idemp;  --substitution variable 
v_count INT:=0;
BEGIN
FOR r IN c_emp(v_fname)
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Emp Id: '||r.emp_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('FName: '||r.fname);
    dbms_output.put_line(' ');
    v_count:= v_count+1;
END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Total de Empleados: '||v_count);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A substitution variable is prefixed with `&` and not `$` so your code should be:

```sql
v_fname employee.fname%TYPE:=&Idemp;
```

However, if you want a bind variable, then it should be prefixed with `:`

```sql
v_fname employee.fname%TYPE:=:Idemp;
```

Comment: Why substitution variable doesnt work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering `Pa` when prompted then you need to enclose the substitution reference in single quotes, to make it a string literal when the PL/SQL block is parsed:

```
v_fname employee.fname%TYPE:='&Idemp';
```

That will then be parsed as `... :='Pa';`

As you have it, without the quotes, it would be parsed as `... :=Pa` and it would try to interpret `Pa` as a (nonquoted) identifier; hence the error you are getting.

---

Using substitution variables in PL/SQL is a little odd, though it will work for an anonymous block. The substitution is done by the client (e.g. SQL*Plus) before the PL/SQL, with the substituted value, is passed to the database engine to be parsed and executed. But then, using PL/SQL at all for what you are doing is a little odd, so I imagine it's a contrived exercise.